# counting number of cars that each owner has

Tags: oracle, loops, if-statement, join, plsql

I'm trying to learn plsql and got stuck in understanding some basic stuff. Here is a challenge that I'm trying to solve. 
I have two tables. One holds information about owners and the other is information about cars. I want to to write an **anonymous** block that joins these two tables and with a for loop based on amount of cars that is registered to each owner prints how many cars each person own. furthermore I want an if statement which distinguishes between 1 Car (singular) and 2, 3 Cars (plural).

the tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE owners(
id_nr VARCHAR2(13) PRIMARY KEY,
f_name VARCHAR2(20),
s_name VARCHAR2(20));

CREATE TABLE cars(
reg_nr VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
id_nr REFERENCES owners(pnr),
model VARCHAR2(20),
year NUMBER(4),
date DATE);
```

The result may look like something like this:

19380321-7799, Hans, Anderson, Owns: 1 car

19490321-7899, Mike, Erikson, Owns: 2 cars

.
.
.
etc.

I tried many different ways but each time i get some errors.
I would appreciate any help and hints that helps me understand it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use a single SQL statement with a `GROUP BY` way more efficient and scalable that any cursor approach will ever be.

Comment: Loops should always be the absolute last resort. 99% of the time they can be solved with just plain-jane sql (and should be).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that it's easier with sql and can be solved without loop. But this is a learning exercise and i want to know how this can be done in plsql and with use of loops. thanks!

Comment: The most important thing to learn about PL/SQL is, when it makes sense to use it and when it does not. Hint: this is a case where it does not make sense.

Comment: Please in questions show & explain things that you have tried. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Also: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. [mre]

Comment: thanks @philipxy i'm new here and this is my first question. You are right I had to provide codes that I had tried!

Comment: But there is no code here except table DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one way to do it. If you want to practice loops, you could add a second loop inside to loop over the cars table and print all the cars each owner has.

```
declare
    v_suffix varchar2(1);
begin
    for o in (select owners.id_nr, f_name, s_name,
                (select count(1) from cars where cars.id_nr = owners.id_nr) as num_cars
                from owners)
    loop
        if o.num_cars = 1 
            then v_suffix = null -- singular
            else v_suffix = 's' -- plural
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(o.id_nr || ', ' || o.f_name || ', ' || o.s_name
            || ' Owns: ' || o.num_cars || ' car' || v_suffix);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i get it. I was trying almost the same but i didnt declare v_suffix. That was why it didn't work. Thanks again!